# Silverman/Tate: Rational points on elliptic curves, Exercise 3.15

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, algebraic-groups

I have a question regarding problem 3.15 of the book *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves* by J. Silverman and John Tate.

Let A be a non-zero rational number that is not a perfect square, i.e. $\sqrt{A} \notin \mathbb{Q}$. In part (a), I showed that the set of rational points lying on the conic curve $u^2-Av^2=1$ form a group with the operation$(u_1,v_1)*(u_2,v_2) = (u_1u_2+Av_1v_2,u_1v_2+u_2v_1)$.
In part (c) one is to show that this curve is not finitely generated by showing that it is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(A))^*$.
I have no idea which subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(A))^*$ could be used for this and how the proof could be done. I am an undergraduate student who just has had his first contacts with algebraic-curves. Therfore I dont have too much tools to tackle this problem.

I would be glad if someone could help me :)

Comment: Thinking about which subgroup it should be isomorphic with is perhaps not the most useful approach. Instead, try to find a map from your group to $\mathbb{Q}^*$ - hopefully it is injective, and you will be done :) Try to look at how your group operation works, and how it could relate to multiplication in $\mathbb{Q}$, this should give you the right idea to construct a homomorphism.

Comment: It is (canonically) a certain subgroup of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{A})^*$ not $\Bbb{Q}^*$

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $C$ the set of rational points of $u^2-Av^2$. As @reuns points out in the comments and the authors suggest in the excercise, we should try to show that $C$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{A})^*$, not of $\mathbb{Q}^*$.

Consider the map $f: C \to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{A})^*$ defined by $f(u,v)=u+\sqrt{A}v$. Note $f(u,v)$ is indeed nonzero because $A$ is not a perfect square and $(0,0) \not \in C$.

It is easy to check that $f$ is a group homomorphism. It is also injective, for if $f(u,v)=1$, then $u=1$ and $v=0$ (again because $A$ is not a perfect square). Hence the result follows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know this homomorphism, but I don't know that img(f) is not finitly generated.